# Drawing Hypergraph using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, graphs

I want to draw a Hypergraph using Ti*k*Z that looks like this

[image: Connection Hypergraph]

What I have so far:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, fit, shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    he/.style={draw, rounded corners},        % he = hyper edge
    ce/.style={draw, dashed, rounded corners} % ce = condition edge
]

\node (f) at (0,0) {$F$};
\node (g) at (1,0) {$G$};
\node (e) at (2,0) {$E$};
\node (d) at (2,1) {$D$};
\node (a) at (2,2) {$A$};
\node (b) at (3,2) {$B$};

\node [he, fit=(f) (g)] {};
\node [ce, fit=(g) (e)] {};
\node [he, fit=(a) (d) (e)] {};
\node [ce, fit=(a) (b) (d)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX Hypergraph]

I didn't manage to ..

- Make the hyperedges a little bit smaller like in the original picture, so that you can distinguish between hyperedges and condition edges
- Make the ABD condition edge a triangle with rounded corners

Do you have any ideas how to do this? Furthermore, this is my first time working with Ti*k*Z, so if you have any other recommendations on how to improve the way of creating this graph and how to define styles, I would be happy to learn more.

Comment: you can give `inner sep=0pt` in style definition of `he` to make hyper edges smaller

Comment: Thanks @nidhin. So far I tried to adjust the box sizes with `scale`, but `inner sep` works better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the `inner sep` of hyper edge or conditional edge so that they both will have different sizes.

I don't have a good solution for the second part using `fit` library. I just drew that conditional edge.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, fit, shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    he/.style={draw, rounded corners,inner sep=0pt},        % he = hyper edge
    ce/.style={draw,dashed, rounded corners=10pt}, % ce = condition edge
]

\node (f) at (0,0) {$F$};
\node (g) at (1,0) {$G$};
\node (e) at (2,0) {$E$};
\node (d) at (2,1) {$D$};
\node (a) at (2,2) {$A$};
\node (b) at (3,2) {$B$};

\node [he, fit=(f) (g)] {};
\node [ce, fit=(g) (e)] {};
\node [he, fit=(a) (d) (e)] {};
\node [fit=(a) (b) (d)] (fd){};
\draw [dashed,rounded corners=10pt] ($(fd.south west)+(0,-0.5)$) -- (fd.north west) -- ($(fd.north east)+(0.5,0)$)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just about to figure out how to draw a triangle around the nodes like you did, but I hard-coded the coordinates of the corners which is very tedious if I would ever want to add another triangle to the graph again. Your solution looks fine, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use my (semi) library (https://gitlab.com/gruenwald/tikz-hypergraphs) that I made for exactly this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}             % For tikz-hypergraph
\usetikzlibrary{calc}           % For tikz-hypergraph
\input{tikz-hypergraph}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    he/.style={draw, semithick},        % he = hyper edge
    ce/.style={draw, dashed, semithick}, % ce = condition edge
]

\node (f) at (0,0) {$F$};
\node (g) at (1,0) {$G$};
\node (e) at (2,0) {$E$};
\node (d) at (2,1) {$D$};
\node (a) at (2,2) {$A$};
\node (b) at (3,2) {$B$};

\draw[he] \hedgeii{a}{b}{3mm};
\draw[he] \hedgeii{a}{e}{3mm};
\draw[ce] \hedgeiii{a}{b}{d}{4mm};
\draw[ce] \hedgeii{g}{e}{4mm};
\draw[he] \hedgeii{f}{g}{3mm};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hypergraph using tikz-hypergraph]